# How to make unordered_map from c struct to int in cython?

Tags: c++, struct, cython, unordered-map

How to make unordered_map from c struct to int in cython?

I try to run the following code:
Main.py

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import pyximport


pyximport.install()
from foo import Fun

Fun()
```

Foo.pyx

```
# cython: experimental_cpp_class_def=True
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef cppclass mystruct:
    int i,j

    bint equal_to "operator=="(const mystruct t) const:
         return this.i == t.i and this.j == t.j

    bint myhash "hash"(const mystruct t) const:
         return hash(i)+hash(i) # how to calculate it properly?


def Fun():
    cdef:
        unordered_map[mystruct,int] dDict
        mystruct A

    A.i=111

    dDict[A]=1234
    print A.i
    print dDict[A]
```

foo.pyxbld

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     experimental_cpp_class_def=True,
                     language='C++')
```

I get the following error:

```
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional(109) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::equal_to<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xhash(184) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::equal_to<_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\unordered_map(74) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,
            _Hasher=std::tr1::hash<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>,
            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xhash(191) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Umap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,
            _Ty=int,
            _Tr=stdext::_Hash_compare<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,std::tr1::hash<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>,std::equal_to<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const __pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,int>>,
            _Mfl=false
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\unordered_map(86) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hash<_Traits>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Traits=std::tr1::_Umap_traits<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,int,stdext::_Hash_compare<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,std::tr1::hash<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>,std::equal_to<__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const __pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,int>>,false>
        ]
        C:\Users\LENOVO\.pyxbld\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyrex\foo.cpp(796) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct,
            _Ty=int
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional(1265) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const __pyx_t_3foo_mystruct' to 'size_t'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional(1264) : while compiling class template member function 'size_t std::tr1::hash<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Kty &) const'
        with
        [
            _Kty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct
        ]
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xhash(183) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::hash<_Kty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=__pyx_t_3foo_mystruct
        ]
```

How should I properly define hash function and correct the program to make it work?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to calculate properly the hash value; The problem is to tell the std C++ lib to use the one which you defined. For this you either

- have to overload `std::hash<mystruct>` but this cannot be done from Cython as far as I know
- or to pass the extra template parameter which forces you to re-wrap all the `unordered_map` stuff since Cython only wrap the two parameter default version. And this is not counting the fact that you will have to hack to pass a non type template parameter from Cython since this is not yet supported.

So my short answer would be : write a real C++ wrapper file.

Comment: Is it still impossible to do this from Cython?

Comment: @Pastafarianist Yes, AFAIK, this will require [this PR](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/426) to be merged for passing non-type template parameters.

Comment: @jseabold I have found a pretty short solution which does involve a "real C++ wrapper" but requires very little extra code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34580622/1214547

Comment: Is this now possible without that extra cpp wrapper code?

Comment: As of 2020, it looks like this is possible in unordered_map https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/unordered_map.pxd

https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3685